# Как разместить фото на карте?

Tags: javascript, node.js, map

После того, как пользователь заполняет форму и отправляет на сервер. Фотографию необходимо поместить на карту в виде маркера. в схеме фотографии задано `latitude` и `longitude`  Отдельно реализована функция, которая извлекает геоданные из exif:

```js
var ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage;
try {
    new ExifImage({ image : 'myImage.jpg' }, function (error, exifData) {
        if (error)
            console.log('Error: '+error.message);
        else {
            var latRef = exifData.gps.GPSLatitudeRef === 'N' ? 1 : -1;
            var longRef = exifData.gps.GPSLongitudeRef === 'E' ? 1 : -1;
            var lat = exifData.gps.GPSLatitude;
            var long = exifData.gps.GPSLongitude;
            var gps = {
                latitude: latRef * (lat[0]+ (lat[1]/60)+(lat[2]/3600)),
                longtitude: longRef * (long[0] + (long[1]/60) + (long[2]/3600))
            };

            console.log(gps);
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
}
```

Обработчик добавления записи:

```js
 app.post('/addPhoto',function (req, res) {
        var phts = req.files.filePhotos;
        if (!req.files){
        }
        var photoName = './public/uploads/'+Date.now()+phts.name;
        phts.mv(photoName);
        var data = req.body;
        data.filePhoto = photoName;
        var newPhoto = new Photo(data);
        console.log(newPhoto, data);
        newPhoto.save(function(err, temp){
            console.log(temp);
            if(err){
                console.log("ooopssss....");
            }
        });
       res.redirect('/');
    } ) ;
```

добавление фотомаркера. Не понимаю как тут задать цикл foreach и в нем перебрать все фото, в которых заданы параметры долготы и широты

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 45.42216, lng: 50.31308}
    });

    setMarkers(map);
    // var photoGPS = {
    //
    // };
    //
    // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //     position: map.getCenter(),
    //     icon: photoGPS,
    //     map: map
    // });
}

var GPScoordinates = []; //задаются геоданные для маркеров

//добавление маркеров на карту
function setMarkers(map) {
    var image = {
        photo: filePhoto, //в качестве маркера - загружаемая пользователем фотография
        size: new google.maps.Size(20,32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0)
    };

    //определение зоны клика
    var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };

    for (var i=0; i<GPScoordinates.length; i++){
        var  gpscoord = GPScoordinates[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: gpscoord[1], lng: gpscoord[2]},
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: gpscoord[0],
            zIndex: gpscoord[3]
        });
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Так Вам нужен один маркер или несколько, и зачем в таком случае вам "перебирать" картинки

Comment: @ddeadlink, каждая добавленная фотография должна отображаться на карте в виде маркера

Comment: Если у Вас `photoGPS` константа из значений, то Вам нужно делать цикл для создания объектов из маркеров, а уж потом передать их в `map`. Можете глянуть пример https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: @ddeadlink, к сожалению, по указанной ссылке  нет кода

Comment: попробуйте https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=ru в разделе `сложные значки`

Comment: @ddeadlink, не совсем понятно из примера. В примере в качестве маркера задается флаг по url, а мне необходимо указать фотографию, которую загружает пользователь через форму.  В пост внесены изменения взятые с примера. Как правильно задать `var GPScoordinates=[]` (в примере задаются конкретные координаты и названия мест) и  в `photo: filePhoto` заношу файл загружаемый пользователем

Comment: я так понимаю ваш обьект `ExifImage` и хранит нужные Вам координаты